# How can I install python-binance package in Pycahrm? (I am using the conda interpreter for my project)

Tags: pip, pycharm, package

I am trying to install the Python-binance package to Pycharm, but it is not available for the conda interpreter that I use.

When I try to install it via `'conda install python-binance'` in my terminal I get the following error:

```
(base) patrickchong@Patricks-MacBook-Pro ~ % conda install python-binance
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python-binance

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Which is strange, because it installs fine when I run 'pip install python-binance'.

Any help would be much appreciated!

- Thanks to Flying Teller's comments below I managed to install python-binance using conda. However, in my Python interpreter, which uses conda, python-binance still doesn't appear? (when I click the + sign and look for python-binance it is not there?)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing unexpected happening here. `pip` and `conda` use different sources for their packages. `pip` always checks PyPi on which `python-binance` is available. `conda` looks for packages in a list of configured channels, in you case, the default channels. But if you check with the [search function](https://anaconda.org/search?q=python-binance) on anaconda.org, you can see that the package is only available from `conda-forge`, so you can install it from `conda` using

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-binance
```

Comment: Thank you so much Flying Teller, I managed to get it installed. One more thing in my question above if you wouldn't mind!

Comment: FlyingTeller, I am quite new to this- to install it into my conda Python interpreter, do I use my terminal to go to the directory and then install it in there?

Comment: If you need to install it to an environment, as is the case here, you would do in your terminal: `conda activate "AlgoExpert Questions"` followed by the install command

Comment: You re a legend, thank you FlyingTeller, it worked! Do you know where I can learn more about interpreters and things like this? - or do you think the best way to learn is to ask the community questions?

Comment: There is the `conda` docs and also a cheat-sheet [available](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/cheatsheet.html)